# How to draw shapes inside JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jpanel, java-2d

Referring to my earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964266/java-how-to-deal-with-graphics):

Based on your valuable answers, I choose [Java 2D library](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html) to cater my requirements.

I completely read the above said library and have full understanding of dealing with the graphics stuff, like what to draw and how to draw etc.Now i only left with one question that how do i draw my required shapes inside JPanel and after drawing all those shapes how do i place that JPanel inside a JScrollPane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method.
Cast `Graphics` to `Graphics2D` and use `drawShape()` method passing all your Shapes

Answer (score 3):

You will typically draw your stuff inside a subclass of JComponent, say, MyComponent.

1. Create an instance of MyComponent, `MyComponent myc = new
   MyComponent();`
2. Put that inside a JScrollPane, e.g. `JScrollPane jsp =
   new JScrollPane(myComponent);`
3. Then add the JScrollpane to the
   JPanel (exact code depends on the layout manager)